# Stock Variance-Covariance Matrix, Multiple Currencies

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix

If i have a portfolio of stocks from different currencies and i want to generate a Variance covariance matrix what is the correct procedure ?

Imagine a set of stocks which trade in USD, EUR, GBP, CAD, AUD with the base currency being EUR. The correct way to generate a variance covariance matrix is :

a) Use the returns on the stocks in local currency (EUR, USD, GBP,CAD, AUD)

b) Use the returns on the stocks in base currency by converting the prices of each stock in EUR at the current FX for the specific date the prices are used

c) Other Solution

Comment: Of these two options, only b) is reasonable. If you use a) you lose the variance from currency translation.

Comment: @MattF.thanks that's what I thought but wasn't sure this would cause any problem with the matrix (i.e. negative eigenvalues)